# Using jQuery to check a checkbox based on text values from other div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, checkbox

I want to check a checkbox based on the values from another `div`. For example, I want the checkbox to be checked if this page has text name `title`. If it doesn't have a `title` then the checkbox won't be checked.

```
<div class="testdiv">
    <p>title</p>
</div>

<div class="checkbox">
    <input type="checkbox" name="testcheck" id="testcheck" value="1">
    <label for="testcheck">Lorem Ipsum</label>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest this way:

```
if ($('#testdiv > p:contains("title")').length > 0) {
    $("#testcheck").prop('checked', true);
}
```

---

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="testdiv">
  <p>title</p>
</div>

<div class="checkbox">
  <input type="checkbox" name="testcheck" id="testcheck" value="1">
  <label for="testcheck">Lorem Ipsum</label>
</div>
```

Basically you are already checking over the selector, if the p contains any text, and then set the checkbox true.

Working testcase:

http://jsfiddle.net/tmanb34t/

Answer (score 0):

```js
var val = $('.testdiv').find('p').text();

if (val == 'title') {
  $('#testcheck').prop('checked', true)
} else {
  $('#testcheck').prop('checked', false)
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="testdiv">
  <p>title</p>
</div>

<div class="checkbox">
  <input type="checkbox" name="testcheck" id="testcheck" value="1">
  <label for="testcheck">Lorem Ipsum</label>
</div>
```

Try this way

first get the text of the p. the text you want to compare. then use if condition to compare if true use `.prop()` to set the checkbox to checked

Answer (score 0):

This should be enough:

```
if($('div').text().indexOf('title')!=-1)
// check the checkbox
```